# SQL update shows successfully updated message but does not update the value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do an update with the condition below:

```
SettlementAmount = CollectionAmount - (CollectionAmount * (3 / 100))
```

And this is what I'm doing:

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[QuoteOptions] 
 SET SettlementAmount = CollectionAmount - (CollectionAmount * (3 / 100)) 
 FROM [dbo].[Quotes]
 JOIN [dbo].[QuoteOptions] ON [dbo].[Quotes].Id = [dbo].[QuoteOptions].QuoteId
 WHERE [dbo].[Quotes].PaymentProfileId = 43 
   AND SettlementAmount = CollectionAmount
```

When I run this query, I get a message that two rows have been affected, but they are not actually! Could anyone be so kind as tell me what mistake I'm making?

```
collectionAmount is = 100
settlementAmount = 100
```

I want to make

```
settlementAmount = collectionAmount - (100 * (3 / 100))
```

Comment: Turn the UPDATE into a SELECT to see what comes back, what the current value is, and what the updated value would be. Then you can better see what is actually being written (and why it is not what you expected it to be).

Comment: @Igor how do you mean? by turning?

Comment: Probably you are using SQL Server which does integer division between integers and this means that 3/100 returns 0. Change to `3.0/100`

Comment: `update [dbo].[QuoteOptions] set SettlementAmount=CollectionAmount-(CollectionAmount* (3/100))...` becomes `SELECT SettlementAmount, CollectionAmount, CollectionAmount-(CollectionAmount* (3/100)) FROM your joins WHERE your filter`. Now you can see what would actually be written and what rows are being affected. This is a good troubleshooting tip for any UPDATE statement (or even DELETE statement).

Comment: @forpas hell yes,that was the issue